FF 10 hd remaster missing record book for dodging lightning
I have a strange problem in ff-10-hd-remaster on PS4.
I'm pretty far in the story. In the thunder planes I miss this record book for dodging lightning.
Is this somehow missable?

I mean this little blue book on the table. (shot is from PS2 version)

Did you already start dodging multiple lightning strikes in a row? I believe the book only appears once you reach the first milestone (5 dodges in a row for 2x X-Potions).

i can not remember i started the game last year and now I play it to the end @Pilzkopf

no way I Ioad an old save file from PS2 (dodged only 3 times) and from PS4 game the book is not there in PS4 game.  Same story progress the 1. arrival in the thunderplains.

Mind that the rewards are given out for successful dodges in a row. If you get hit or leave the screen / transition elsewhere your streak is set back to 0. Perhaps you never reached 5 dodges in a row?

That I know but the book should be at least there so I could read it?

According to this guide the book appears after you dodge two lightning strikes in a row. Two singular dodges apparently do not work. There's a key difference between dodging X times and dodging X times in a row.

Oh i will never achive this :( thank you for finding this out.

No need to give up. There's some advice on how to do it right here. And even if getting 200 dodges in a row is daunting just going for a few can be quite worthwhile as well.

In the HD Version not a Chance i Play the ps2 one in pcsx2 there i geht the sigil for lulu but Not in hell  HD Version

@Pilzkopf please make your comment  with the wikilink as an answer so i can Accept IT after flipping around in TV Menu i have less lag with Controller ️ Input and the book appears.

According to this guide the stat book will only appear once you have dodged two lightning strikes in a row.
Successful dodges must be in a row - getting hit by lightning, leaving the current area or starting an activity like playing Blitzball will end this streak.
